# ReactJS: Rendering SVG tags within SVG container fails in Safari

Tags: svg, safari, reactjs

In the markup,

```
<html>
    <svg>
        <g>Test</g>
        <g id="existing-g"></g>
    <svg>
</html>
```

In JavaScript:

```
React.render(<text>Something</text>, document.getElementById('existing-g'));
```

- React renders SVG elements well within an HTML element container on all the browsers
- But, In Safari, React doesn't render SVG within SVG element container. Though it works well in Firefox and Chrome.
- May be Safari doesn't support some of the APIs on SVG DOM Node to append elements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

React uses `innerHTML` attribute when mounting components. `innerHTML` attribute isn't available on SVG elements by default in many browsers.

I used this polyfill https://code.google.com/p/innersvg/ which adds the `innerHTML` attribute on SVG elements. It solved the problem.